# How to pass a put extra value through Imagebutton called from Array Adapter in Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-viewholder, android-imagebutton

I have a n Array Adapter with a viewHolder.

Inside adapter I implement a imagebutton click listener which opens another activity.

I want to pass an id to the second activity but it says

it cannot resolve method

```
viewHolder.discounts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Discounts.class);
            intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(id));
            ((Services) getContext()).startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

**How to pass this to another activity?**

Comment: u have 2 apply a key where u want to pass the value of id. For e.g intent.putExtra("id",String.valueOf(id));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(id));
```

With

```
intent.putExtra("id",String.valueOf(id));
```

here id is key. you can access it in your second activity like below

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with setOnItemClickListerner for

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position,long id){
   Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Discounts.class);
   intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));
   ((Services) getContext()).startActivity(intent);
  }
 });
```